# TypeError: update_one() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
testdb.update_one({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_id":user_id}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]}, upsert=False)
```

Getting TypeError:

```
update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'. If removed upsert=False, then getting:
TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

What is the correct way to do this python code calling pymongo? Any inputs will be of great help.

Comment: Could you please give full sample code, what are 'i' & 'j' here and also sample data that you are trying to update.

Comment: {
 "id" : "5efb83dc365fb6bdb3b78a9a",
 "testArrayLevel1" : [
                {
                       "user_id": "test_user1"
                        "testArrayLevel2" : [
                                {
                                        user_type: "basic"
                                        "status" : "new",
     ...
     ...
                                        
                                }
                        ]
                },
        ]

}

Comment: When run in mongodb  prompt manually without upsert it works fine. 
     testdb.update({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_id":"test_user1"}, {"j.user_type": "basic"}]})

Comment: 'i' and 'j' are placeholders for the user_id and user_type for setting the field to new value in nested array for the matched  user_id and user_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the way you pass args to function, the `value_args` is malformed, so instead of

```
testdb.update_one({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_id":user_id}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]}, upsert=False)
```

Use right passing for `value_args`, also formatting will make your life eathier:

```
testdb.update_one({'id': id},
                  {
                      "$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"},
                      "array_filters":[{"i.user_id":user_id}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]
                  },
                  upsert=False)
```

**NOTE** By default upsert is set to false, so may want to consider removing it, as I believe you used same call and the upsert were set to dict, which won't be the case after fixing arguments.

Comment: Thanks. After modifying, getting new error: pymongo.errors.WriteError: No array filter found for identifier 'i' in path 'orders.$[i].order_items.$[j].status'

Comment: @Anand I think since that answers your question you can accept that one and create new question.

Comment: When run in mongodb prompt manually and without modifying any value_args (original) it worked fine.  testdb.update({'id': id},   {"$set":  
 {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}  },  {"array_filters":[{"i.user_id":"test_user1"}, {"j.user_type": "basic"}]  }  )

Comment: @Anand I think since that answers your question you can accept that one and create new question.   <br/> The args passing may not be correct which is leading to new error.

Comment: @Anand please get familiar with that and update or delete your question respectivelty: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Question is not the thread for getting task done...

Answer (score 1):

The right usage is here ( got the right comamnd after posting another question):

mongo.db.testdb.update_one({'id': id}, 
{"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status': "registered"}}, 
                        **array_filters=**[{"i.user_name": user_name}, {"j.user_type": user_type}],

upsert=False)

Answer (score 0):

try just with "update" not "update_one".

testdb.update({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_id":user_id}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]}, upsert=False)

Answer (score 0):

you can done this type
data is:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "user" : "usr_name",
    "tasks_list" : [
        {
            "task_id" : "dc12210e-5bc9-41c1-af55-adcdec09de8c",
            "status" : "running",
            "info" : "extract_group"
        }
    ]
}
```

solution:

```
tasks.update_one(filter={"user":usr},
                 update={"$set":{"tasks_list.$[elem].status":"complite"}},
                 upsert=False,array_filters=[{"elem.task_id":task_id}])
```